# MySQL - Username to connect using Query browser

Tags: mysql, browser

I'm fairly new to my sql, and I need to know what is the default username for mysql, like in mssql you have 'sa'.

I can connect to the mysql command client but it does not ask me for a username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "sa" in mysql is root

Comment: The default schema is the database schema you want to "use" immediately after connect. You can change it later with the "use" command. Every non-qualified statement (SELECT * FROM table;) will refer to the current default schema. Otherwise you'd have to write SELECT * FROM schemaname.table;